# Tkinter create multiple buttons in a frame

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI using Pkinter. I need to make lots of buttons, and right now I created about 50 buttons take covers whole screen(expands and fill). I am trying to put these buttons in a Frame that way I can add more frames on the side. I saw other posts which was suggesting to take of Grid but I couldn't figure out how to Position 60 buttons without Grid option.

Here is my code.

```
def create_buttons(self):
    Grid.rowconfigure(self.root, 0, weight=1)
    Grid.columnconfigure(self.root, 0, weight=1)
    card_frame = Frame(self.root)
    card_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
    # Create a 5x10 (rows x columns) grid of buttons inside the frame
    i = 0
    for row_index in range(5):
        Grid.rowconfigure(card_frame, row_index, weight=1)
        for col_index in range(10):
            # Set card image
            card_image_path = "assets/Card_Orange_gif/" + str(i) + ".gif"
            card_image = PhotoImage(file=card_image_path)
            small_card_image = card_image.subsample(2, 2)
            # Create button
            Grid.columnconfigure(card_frame, col_index, weight=1)
            btn = Button(card_frame,
                         width=5, height=5,
                         image=small_card_image,
                         bg="azure",
                         borderwidth=0,
                         command=lambda i = i: self.card_button_clicked(i))
            btn.image = small_card_image
            btn.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky=N+S+E+W)

            i = i+1
}
```

Here is my ideal result. (can't add photo, here is link ) https://paste.pics/46XES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the rowconfigure and columnconfigure correctly. You have not stated how you want the layout to react to size change so I'm just doing uniform expansion of every widget:

```
from tkinter import *

class spam():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.create_buttons()
        self.create_rest_of_layout()

    def create_buttons(self):
        # Configure root window for rows and cols according to "ideal result"
        self.root.rowconfigure([0,1,2], weight=1)
        self.root.columnconfigure([0,1], weight=1)
        card_frame = Frame(self.root)
        card_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

        # Configure 5 rows and 10 columns
        card_frame.rowconfigure([0,1,2,3,4], weight=1)
        card_frame.columnconfigure([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], weight=1)

        # Create a 5x10 (rows x columns) grid of buttons inside the frame
        i = 0
        for row_index in range(5):
            for col_index in range(10):
                # Set card image
                card_image = PhotoImage(file='beer.png')
                small_card_image = card_image.subsample(2, 2)
                # Create button
                btn = Button(card_frame,
                             width=5, height=5,
                             image=small_card_image,
                             bg="azure",
                             borderwidth=0,
                             command=lambda i=i: self.card_button_clicked(i))
                btn.image = small_card_image
                btn.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky=N+S+E+W)
                i = i+1

    def card_button_clicked(self,x):
        print(x)

    def create_rest_of_layout(self):
        # Create the rest of the frames
        a = Label(self.root, text='middle', bg='tan')
        a.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        b = Label(self.root, text='bottom', bg='khaki')
        b.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        c = Label(self.root, text='top right', bg='bisque')
        c.grid(rowspan=2, row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        d = Label(self.root, text='bottom right', bg='gold')
        d.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)

root = Tk()
spam(root)

root.mainloop()
```

I'm thinking this is probably not the desired layout solution but it gives you something to play with in trying to get there.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to do some work, but I was able to set up Frames!